# hyperref package - link boxes are too small (overlap the text)

Tags: hyperref, miktex, dvipdfmx

The boxes the hyperref package creates around links in my document are too small, hiding out the characters.  I'm using latex to get a DVI, then dvi2pdfm to get a PDF.  Both from MikTex 2.8.     Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\section{Example} \label{example}
Section \ref{example}.
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the picture below, the resulting box overlaps the "2".  Below it is how I expect it to look, copied from some PDF on the web (not mine).

[image]

I get the same problem if I use the "hypertex" driver in hyperref.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Andrey, `pdflatex` works, thanks!  It means I have to use `epstopdf` for my images and slow down the first compilation, but I can live with that.  Still I'm curious about the original problem.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `latex->dvi2pdfm`? Are you importing EPS or using PSTricks code? If your input file (.tex file) imports PNG, JPEG or PDF files, you should use `pdflatex`. If it does not solve the issue, try update your MikTeX.

Comment: @xport, yes I'm importing EPS.

Answer (score 2):

use the driver `dvips` and then run `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Sadly it adds an extra step.  So is the problem in dvipdfm?

Comment: yes, I think so