# Why are the hyperref boxes always the wrong size

Tags: hyperref

In almost every document I have ever seen, the red boxes that hyperlink equations are always a little bit to small for the numbers. Here is a symple example I wrote in overleaf, but the problem is prolific.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Here is my equation

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:my_eqn}
    a = b.
\end{equation}

I reference the equation as \ref{eq:my_eqn}
\end{document}
```

I awknowledge the question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/hyperref-package-link-boxes-are-too-small-overlap-the-text), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267971/a-problem-with-the-size-of-hyperref-boxes-around-links), but I did not find a "quick fix" answer in either of them. The former asks me to "use the driver dvips and then run latex->dvips->ps2pdf" which is beyond my limited understanding of overleaf, and the latter seems to be on a slightly different topic.

[image: an example of hyperref messing up the boxes]

Comment: Have you tried to download the pdf and use another pdf viewer? I can reproduce this in the overleaf pdf viewer, but it looks fine with local viewers.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZKZZ.png

Comment: even if the viewer shows them at the right size, they are unspeakably ugly, I'd always use the colorlinks option in hyperref to show links in color or bold rather than using these boxes.

Comment: As the above comments noted (without exactly saying it): Depiction of the link box is determined by the PDF reader software. But if you use unboxed, color links, no (known) problem.

Comment: it seems to be a problem of the overleaf viewer, so report that to the overleaf support.